# Best data structure for ordered pair

Tags: java, data-structures

so I need to find the best easy-to-work-with data structure for the following ordered pair:
Let's assume I got 6 different classes, each with his own class-type **that extends class A** and another class of **B**.
The user will provide me with ordered pairs of

```
(Class<? extends A> type, B m)
```

I need a data structure to hold the pairs, be able to access them later, delete some of them etc
The number of possible **Class ? extends A**  type**s** is final so I thought I can maintain a list or something for each different type, but thought there might be a more elegant way to achieve that.

Another thing is that for every **type B** I need to hold a Queue for it.

The naive solution was to maintain a list for each **Class ? extends A  type** which every list will hold the relevant **type B** elements, and another queue for each **type B**

Comment: It's called [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: @Andreas I provided some more information